# A two successive wheel trailer ; would it work? (followme-tandem)

Tags: trailer, children, tandems

TL;DR Why does the [followme-tandem](http://www.followme-tandem.com/) have the kids front wheel off the ground?

[image]

I'm looking into the [followme-tandem](http://www.followme-tandem.com/), which attaches a child's bicyle to the back of an adult's bike to make a trailer-bike. The child's front wheel is elevated from ground. I deduce from the manual that the connection swivels up-down around the adult's rear axis and left-right around a joint between the bikes.

I'm wondering why the product is designed to raise the front wheel in the air?

Would the bikes be difficult to ride if also the kid's front wheel would touch ground?

(The reason I ask is: I doubt I could support the extra weight in addition to the child seat and panniers I'm already carrying on my rack. So, could I not set up the follow-me so that the front wheel is in contact with ground, thus not needing vertical support?)

EDIT: Answer to my specific problem: There is no need to worry about supporting the extra weight. **As long as the tandem is connected directly onto the axis of the parent's bike, the trailer produces no torque around the back axis!** The weight goes directly to the wheel.

Comment: The effect of the child trying to steer might be interesting (or the steering flopping around)

Comment: The current design doesn't require the child's bike to use steering. This would have to be the case if the front wheel touches the ground. If you wanted that, you could effectively use a tow line. With a rigid connection I believe steering would be easier with a longer connection rather the extremely short one as in this design.

Comment: What they said.  At best the unit will whip back and forth as you ride, being very unpleasant for both riders, and unstable.  And it is apt to "jackknife" with little warning.

Comment: @ChristianLindig A tow line would be very different, since then the child would have to brake and could also drift to the sides.

Comment: A trailer with steered front wheel wouldn't have to be steered by the child; the towing bar could be attached to the handlebars and fork, not the main frame. However, (simplifying) single track vehicles steer by leaning/counter-steering, so you would probably only be able to tow a tricycle like that, and the linkage would be difficult with a towing bike which leans and changes the height of the tow point. One tricycle towing another should be possible though. (Or vehicles with more than three wheels of course - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road_train)

Comment: The picture now in the post means you wouldn't have to worry about the weight - it would go directly to the axle

Comment: If you look carefully at the image I just edited in, there's a bar going from the front wheel that locks out the child's steering.

Comment: Chris H solved my problem by pointing out that connection directly to the axle removes the problem of supporting the weight. (There is no torque. )  However, the formal question  in the title remains only partially solved.

Comment: It wasn't me, it was @RoboKaren who solved it by finding that picture. I hadn't seen one constructed like that until that edit.

Comment: Depending on the state you're in and the highway, you occasionally come up upon a 4-wheel trailer being towed by a truck at fairly high speed.  (In most states such trailers are illegal.)  The trailer will zig-zag back and forth in the lane, especially if it's windy, and one suspects it's a bear for the driver to control.  And around here we see a lower speed  version of this with farm tractors towing grain bins.  They still wobble around quite a bit, but the lower speed means they aren't so unmanageable.

Comment: @DanielRHicks It's not at all clear to me what kind of trailer you mean, or how this is relevant to the question. You mean the kind with a stearable axle at the front and a rigid axle at the back, pulled by a drawbar? I'd be kinda surprised if they were illegal anywhere; UPS and other parcel companies use them extensively, and it's legal to tow _two_ of those in several states. The kind with two rigid axles in the middle? Something else?

Comment: @DavidRicherby - Yeah, the drawbar style.  Most states have outlawed them, except that the trucking lobby forced through a federal law some years back to force them to be accepted on rural Interstates, or something of that nature.  I haven't seen such a rig here in Minnesota for years.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The follow-me tandem lifts the front wheel of the child's cycle off the ground because that's the only way to have stable handling on corners.

I made some primitive drawings to explain. Note that in these simplified drawings, the radius of the curve is exaggerated.

---

When the two bicycles are going in a straight line, it would be fine if there were four wheels touching the ground. The connection has to be rigid otherwise when the parent brakes, the child would ram into them.

[image: Image of two bicycles]

---

Once you get to a corner, if the connection were rigid and the child's steering were locked out --  the front wheel doesn't have enough traction to actually force the turn. The three tracked rear wheels would force the front wheel to skid before it could make the bike turn. You also can't lean into the turn because of the three rear wheels.

But say the front wheel had infinite grip and the parent infinite strength -- the only way the rear would turn would be for the rear tires to lose grip, whipping the child around and maybe off the bike.

[image: Two bikes with connection]

---

If the connection were rigid and the child's steering wasn't locked out, it would  look like this when traveling at speed. The parent's rear wheel is likely losing traction and skidding laterally at this point:

[image]

---

What would happen if the child's front wheel wasn't locked to the trailer attachment? Again centrifugal force would make the trailer act like a giant whip, jackknifing, and throwing the child off. Note the magnitude of the centrifugal forces acting on the rear bicycle would be greater than even the strongest of superlemur children and they would not be able to hold the handlebars straight to force the rear into alignment.

[image: Unlocked front wheel]

---

What happens if we have a hinged attachment but lock out the child's steering? Here, it would work but there's a lot of lateral force acting on the front tire of the child's cycle going around corners because it can't track properly. The worst case scenario is that it would actually roll the tire off of the wheel rim. The front wheel would eat the tube, lock, and the child would break their face on their handlebars. Not good childrearing practice.

[image: Hinged attachment locked steering]

---

**Followme's design:** By putting a hinge in the trailer attachment and by lifting up the front wheel, the bikes track properly. In my diagram, the child's green front wheel indicates that it's part of the trailer attachment and is now locked in position. There is still some centrifugal force (as with all trailers) trying to cause a jackknife but it is relatively manageable as long as the parent doesn't try to corner and brake hard at the same time (bad parent!).

[image: Followme design]

<sub>Fine print: Images copyright by robokaren, cc-by-sa. And yes, I know that centrifugal force does not actually exist, but is a fictitious inertial force. However, it's still handy when explaining things to lay people. And yes, lemur children do have much grippier hands and feet than human children.</sub>

Comment: I think you have a lemur-fixation.  Pictures are very helpful too.

Comment: The alarmism is nice, but I'd like to see explanation how the lateral skidding is achieved and how the system behaves before skidding.

Comment: @ojs I agree I don't see how the second or third example would cause skidding.

Comment: It causes skidding because, in all cases, the system must pivot around one of the unsteered wheels as it turns.